# exclude file type from textmate bundle macros

Tags: macros, textmate, bundle

I would like to know how to code TextMate bundles and how to exclude a file from a certain bundle.

Can you answer the question in [my comment on this textmate whitespace bundle issue](https://github.com/glennr/uber-glory-tmbundle/issues/#issue/1/comment/590856)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Bundles -> Bundle Editor -> Show Bundle Editor
Expand the Uber Glory bundle and select Convert Tabs to Spaces...
In the field labeled Scope Selector, put `- text.html.markdown`

This should make the following additions to the file: `/Macros/Convert Tabs to Spaces, Strip whitespace, save.tmMacro`

```
@@ -51,6 +51,8 @@
        <string>@s</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Convert Tabs to Spaces, Strip whitespace, save</string>
+       <key>scope</key>
+       <string>- text.html.markdown</string>
        <key>uuid</key>
        <string>D6844EF1-342B-46D9-A687-CB402F7F4209</string>
 </dict>
```

Note: If you'd rather make the change by editing the file, make sure to select Bundles -> Bundle Editor -> Reload Bundles